# Django: действия над группой объектов

Tags: django, django-admin

Имеются две модели таблиц

```
class Catalog(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Catalog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Необходимо зайти в список Item выбрать некоторые и переместить их в определенный каталог. К примеру выделенные предметы на картинке, переместить в Каталог 3.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как это можно сделать?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо смотреть в сторону Admin action

- admin.ModelAdmin.action_form
- admin.ModelAdmin.action